# how to launch jhs on remote linux server and get access to it from remote client like chromebook

Tags: linux, j

I'm trying to figure out how to get access to J from remote client because I'm using chromebook. That would require me to put in the address bar of my web browser "123.45.67.89:65001/jijx" instead of "http://localhost:65001/jijx." I installed j on remote linux server. And I typed like following through terminal shell and ended up in fail with abrupt closing of J session. What's wrong with me?

```
    load '~addons/ide/jhs/core.ijs'
    init_jhs_''

J HTTP Server - init OK

Ctrl+c here signals an interrupt to J.

Browse to: http://127.0.0.1:65001/jijx

myname@mine:~$ Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported. ($HOME is /home/myname which is owned by myname.)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should directly load a configuration:

```
load'~addons/ide/jhs/config/jhs.cfg'   NB. default configuration
```

You should allow for the remote IP in the configuration. For example, add the following line to jhs.cfg:

```
BIND =: 'any'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I'll refer to it.

Answer (score 1):

Recent JHS releases no longer require the BIND config parameter.

In your localhost JHS session, click help menu, then wiki JHS, and then Server to get the info you need.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice. I'll try as you mention.